# Trusted user not recognized by powershell

Tags: powershell, certificate, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-client

The following set-up is given:

- We are a fairly small branch of a big enterprise sitting on the bottom of a complex WinServer 2012 R2 AD. Therefore we are somehow restricted in our policies.
- Our development department has three PowerShell developers who want to use their scripts securely.
- We implemented an AD CS to sign our scripts by our own root certificate authority.

The technical steps to implement our certificates are the following:

- Create a private key with a public certificate using openssl.
- Sign the certificate by our certificate authority.
- Import the signed certificate into an AD users account along with the public certificate of the CA into the trusted CAs.
- The certificate user "ScriptUser" is not an AD user, therefore we import his certificate into the trusted users area.

Signing and testing:

- On the client system (Windows 7 or Windows 10) we tested to sign a
  PowerShell script which went ok.
- When running the script locally we get an error message that the **certificate owner is not trustworthy**. After committing the script runs.

We expected the script to run without any dialogue.

What's our fault?